# How to Implement Certain timeout session on multiple pages of a website - REACTJS

Tags: design, web-applications, reactjs

Suppose there 5 pages to a website. User flow will be `1->2->3->4->5->FINISH`. I want to implement is that whenever a user enters page 3 a timer starts and if he doesn't finish a task within that time it is redirected to page 2.

I am thinking of implementing it using a `Higher Order Component(HOC)` which on mount starts the timer. And warpping up the components of pages 3-4-5 (which are part of the session) with the Higher Order Component created earlier.

Any flaw in my approach considering user can open multiple tabs? Any new suggestion?

Comment: what do you mean by flaw? The user can avoid the redirect as its implemented client side

Comment: Am i thinking right?